# MergeMap for each expand occurence

Tags: rxjs

I want to create an `Observable` chain which will be able to add `http` data to each `expand` occurence before the next one and I can't figure out how.

Actual test:

```
Observable.of('')
          .expand(n => n.length < 15 ? Observable.of(n + 'e') : Observable.empty())
          .mergeMap(n => Observable.of(n + 'm'))
          .subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

Output:

```
m
em
eem
eeem
eeeem
eeeeem
```

Expected output:

```
em
emem
ememem
```

The goal of this is to add informations to each `expand` call using an `http` request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function passed to `expand` receives the value that's emitted by `expand`. It doesn't receive the value that's emitted by the entire chain.

So if you want the added information (`m`) to be included in the value passed to said function, the `mergeMap` will have to be composed inside `expand`:

```js
Rx.Observable.of('').expand(n => n.length < 15 ?
    Rx.Observable.of(n + 'e').mergeMap(n => Rx.Observable.of(n + 'm')) :
    Rx.Observable.empty()
)
.subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```